# How to host on demand resources from xcode during development

Tags: ios, xcode7, on-demand-resources

I'm trying to implement on demand resource downloading for my iOS app. The documents allude to the fact that xcode can host asset packs for you during the development process. My question is how do I enable that? Is there another way to test on demand resource downloading during development. Is the "Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle" build setting relevant? Here is where xcode hosting is mentioned in the docs:
[on demand docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingHosting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH18-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed resources in the bundle for local testing and Ad-hoc distribution.

If you want to test ODR downloads you'll need to use Testflight.

Comment: But how to embed resources in bundle for device testing, which Xcode setting was for ODR? Any switch to turn on or off?

Answer (score 15):

There is a flag in the build settings called "Embed Asset Packs In Product Bundle". Set that to YES for Debug builds. This will allow you to simulate resource downloading when building from xcode. In actuality, you will be "downloading" the resources from inside the app bundle.

Comment: Do we need to make it to NO for production build ?